# How to create nested json from mysql tables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

**I have created two tables in the mysql 1st table is cat_names, id and the 2nd table is Qoutes, id iam retriving from php script but i want nested

I have got like this when exiecuted**

```
[{"cat_names":"Animal","Qoutes":"this is id 1st text"},{"cat_names":"Animal","Qoutes":"this is 1st id text"},{"cat_names":"ball","Qoutes":"this is 2nd id text"},{"cat_names":"ball","Qoutes":"this is 2nd id text"},{"cat_names":"cat","Qoutes":"this is 3rd id text"},{"cat_names":"cat","Qoutes":"this is 3rd id text"}]
```

Code :

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pwd = 'root';
$db = 'demoqouteapp';

$conn = mysqli_connect( $host,$user,$pwd,$db);

if( !$conn ) {
   die ("Error in connection:" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$response = array();

$sql_query = "select c.cat_names, q.Qoutes from categories AS c inner join `qoute` as q on c.id = q.id";

$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql_query );

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($response,$row);
    }
} else {

    $response['success'] = 0;
    $response['message'] = 'No data';
}

echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($conn);
```

**I want cat_names in an array and quotes is also in array-like**

```
[{
        "cat_names": "animals",
        "qoutes":  [{
                       "qoutes": "this is 1 st qoute"
                    },
                    {
                       "qoutes": "this is 1 st qoute"
                    }]
 }]
```

Comment: Why are you using mysql for this kind of operation?
you can use any No-SQL or JSON based database for that.

Comment: I am trying to build admin panel, I am a beginner I don't know much I usually require get and post methods

Comment: The thing is that you can create 2 tables( categories and quotes ) and then query them both and create the JSON on your side. 

and you can read that JSON in PHP and create the query for both tables. 
there are some approaches but those are not efficient in these situations.

Answer (score -1):

You want to group the data from several records into one object here - and that is something you need to do yourself.

This is easiest, if you use the category as associative array key first:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if(!isset($response[$row['cat_names']])) {
    $response[$row['cat_names']] = [
      'cat_names' => $row['cat_names'],
      'qoutes' => []
    ];
  }
  $response[$row['cat_names']]['qoutes'][] = ['qoutes' => $row['Qoutes']];
}
```

If `$response[$row['cat_names']]` is not set yet, that means we are dealing with the first record with a particular cat name. In that case, we initialize `$response[$row['cat_names']]` as a new array, and set the `cat_names` in that, and initialize `qoutes` as an empty sub-array.

After that, the current quote (I assume you actually mean that you have *quotes* here, so maybe fix the spelling now, before that gets a hassle later …) gets pushed into the `qoutes` sub-array.

Now we just need to get rid of the associative index on the outer level again - otherwise, encoding this as JSON would give you an object, not an array. This can easily be done using `array_values`, so after your loop you put:

```
$response = array_values($response);
echo json_encode($response);
```

… and you should have what you want.

Comment: i am getting result as [{"cat_names":"Animal","qoutes":{"qoutes":"this is 1st id text"}},{"cat_names":"ball","qoutes":{"qoutes":"this is 2nd id text"}},{"cat_names":"cat","qoutes":{"qoutes":"this is 3rd id text"}}]  i want qoutes as in array list from mysql i want to retrive list of qoutes data iam getting only one

Comment: Sorry, that was missing one set of `[]`, needs to be `$response[$row['cat_names']]['qoutes'][] = ['qoutes' => $row['Qoutes']];` - please try again with that modification.